# Why JSP directives are called directives?

Tags: java, jsp, directive

Does anyone know why JSP directives are called directives?

There are three directives in JSP which are:

```
<%@ page ... %> 
<%@ include ... %>
<%@ taglib ... %>
```

Any insight on how they resemble to be called directives?

Comment: I do appreciate if you let me know why you are giving this question a negative point without any comments.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I'm guessing it's because the question really isn't a good fit for SO, plus it's pretty self-explanatory; directives give directions to the page.

Comment: @Prabhakaran Thanks I have corrected it. You could have corrected it yourself as well. There is no need for a -1 for a dictation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Directives are elements that relay messages to the JSP container and
>   affect how it compiles the JSP page. In other words, JSP directives provide directions
>   and instructions to the container, telling it how to handle certain
>   aspects of JSP processing.

Now if someone is giving so many directions to container then why not logically be called as directives!

Comment: Ashan Thanks, do you mind if I ask you where you have found this description?

Comment: Mainly Oracle official documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnajt/index.html